# Transpose of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Help please...
Let $V = M \oplus N$ be a finite dimensional vector space and assume that $E:V → V$ is a projection on $M$ along $N$. Show that the transpose $E^t : V^* → V^*$ is a projection on $N^\circ$ along $M^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions mean that $Em=m$ and $En=0$ for all $m\in M,\ n\in N$.

Now if $\alpha\in  V^*$, that means $\alpha:V\to K$ where $K$ is the base field, $\ $ then we have
$$E^t(\alpha)\ =\ v\mapsto \alpha(Ev)\,.$$
Since $Ev\in M$ for all $v\in V$, we have $E'(\alpha)=0$ for any $\alpha\in M^\circ$ (that means $\alpha(m)=0$ for all $m\in M$).

Similarly, if $\beta\in N^\circ$, we have $E^t(\beta)\ =\ (m+n)\mapsto\beta(m)$, and as $\beta(n)=0$, $\ \beta(m)=\beta(m)+\beta(n)=\beta(m+n)$, so we obtain
$E^t(\beta)=\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* You may also use that $\ker f^*=({\rm im}\; f)^{\circ}$ and ${\rm im}\;f^*=(\ker  f)^{\circ}$.